# large text breaks column width in table

Tags: html, css, html-table, column-width

I have a table with 3 columns, and for each column i have defined the width. The problem is that the widths that i have defined are never respected, a column will always fit the largest text of that column. How can i disable this behavior, and enforce the column width to stay fixed, no matter how large is the text inside it?

the HTML source:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1Class">...</td>
        <td class="column2Class">...</td>
        <td class="column3Class">...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1Class">...</td>
        <td class="column2Class">...</td>
        <td class="column3Class">...</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

the css source:

```
.column1Class {
    width: 20%;
    }
.column2Class {
    width: 70%;
}

.column3Class {
    width: 10%;
}
```

[image: my desired behavior is to truncate any text that goes beyond the 20% width defined for the first column]    my desired behavior is to truncate any text that goes beyond the 20% width defined for the first column

Comment: Minimal example work fine for me. I think the problem is your other css. Try a minimal example and expand it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Comment: This is not a JSF problem, but a basic HTML/CSS problem. You'd have had exactly the same problem when creating a [mcve] based on JSF-generated HTML output which you can obtain via rightclick, viewsource in browser. I have reformulated your question as such so chances on an answer of HTML/CSS experts increase. Once you get an answer from a HTML/CSS expert, it's a matter of rewriting JSF code in such way that it produces exactly the desired HTML/CSS output.